# issue with ACTION_PICK and what could be used instead?

Tags: android

I have a problem with ACTION_PICK. Code below works well on my Galaxy mini, when i pick photos then it opens my gallery with photos only and when i pick videos then it opens gallery with videos only. However on htc legend first option opens my gallery with both, movies and images and second crash my application coz it's trying to open com.htc.music process. I want to know how can i solve this problem with acion_pick or what could be used instead of this?

<

```
code>
case ATT_GALLERY_PHOTO : { 
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI );
startActivityForResult(i, ACTIVITY_GALLERY_PHOTO ); 
break;
} 

case ATT_GALLERY_MOVIE : {
Intent movieIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI );
startActivityForResult(movieIntent, ACTIVITY_GALLERY_MOVIE ); 
break;
}
</code>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` instead of `ACTION_PICK` and see if it helps.

Comment: It works great! thx a lot =) However ACTION_PICK still can be used if you call function setType( String type ) on calling intent. for ex: Intent i = new Intent( Intent.ACTION_PICK ).setType( "video/*" );